# How to specify optional sort key in Python

Tags: python, sorting

I have a function where I want to allow passing in an optional sorting function. If no function is passed in, I want to sort with the default function. Is there a better way than one of these options?

## Use if function to avoid passing a key. Fast but code is ugly.

```
def do_the_thing(self, sort_func=None):
  if sort_func is None:
    for item in sorted(self.items):
       ....
  else:
    for item in sorted(self.items, key=sort_func):
       ....
```

## Use default sort function - slower?

```
def do_the_thing(self, sort_func=lambda x: x):
  for item in sorted(self.items, key=sort_func):
    ....
```

Comment: `sorted(iterable, /, *, key=None, reverse=False)` is the default signature of `sorted` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `None`, `sorted` understands that:

```
>>> sorted([6,2,5,1], key=None)
[1, 2, 5, 6]
```

An identity function was [proposed, but rejected](https://bugs.python.org/issue1673203).

Comment: So obvious, yet so easy to overlook! Thanks :)